# Primary receiver refunds a chained payment from their PayPal account; what happens?

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I'm developing a PayPal chained payment app where

- Primary receiver = the service provider, gets 90% of payment
- Secondary receiver = marketplace, gets 10% of payment

It's all working in the Sandbox environment, but there's a snag - when the primary receiver logs into their PayPal account, and manually refunds a payment they received, the secondary receiver doesn't appear to return their 10% automatically.

E.g.:

1. Primary receiver was paid $100, passed $10 automatically to
   secondary receiver.
2. Primary receiver decides to refund using PayPal
   account interface.
3. Refund for $100 issued; but secondary receiver
   keeps their $10. Primary receiver now out of pocket by $10.

I would like it so that the secondary receiver automatically refunds their portion of a payment if the primary receiver issues a refund.

From reading the documentation from the Refund API (https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/Refund_API_Operation/), I thought this was the default behaviour, no matter if the refund was initiated through an API call or manually through the PayPal account interface.

Do I have this wrong, or is it just a bug with the Sandbox environment?

Would be useful to have this cleared up, as couldn't find any existing threads on the matter.

**Update**

PayPal Technical Support have told me the following:

> Thank you for contacting Merchant Technical Services.
>   From my understanding you would like to have when a primary receiver perform a refund, the secondary receiver will automatically issued a refund.
>   If you would like all the receiver to refund the amount, you have to pass the paykey. May I know how the payment was made? If it is using Pay API operation, you have to use Refund API in order to refund the transaction. The refund can't be done by using PayPal account.

Comment: were you able to solve this issue? sorry.. I know it's long time ago, but I am facing the same problem here. (mine is through the API)

Answer (score 0):

Use the payKey of the original transaction in the refund API, it will solve your problem.
And in case if you wish to partially refund the amount, specify the amount to be deducted from primary and secondary receivers in the "receiverList" field.
For more, refer: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/Refund_API_Operation/#table-3-additional-fields-for-refunds-of-specific-amounts-to-specific-receivers